# Не возвращается значение из потока

Tags: java, android

Есть поток которое получает с сайта имя пользователя:

```
    public class ThreadNews extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL (strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr =new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bRead=new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sBuilder=new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line=bRead.readLine())!=null){
                sBuilder.append(line);
            }
            isr.close();
            inputStream.close();
            return sBuilder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Во время выполнения строки `return sBuilder.toString();` значение sBuilder="Admin", но когда я получаю это значение из потока:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
    final EditText userInputLogin = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.itLogin);
    final EditText userInputPass = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.itPass);
    mDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Вход", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"asdsa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        Res= new ThreadNews().execute("http://newsyou.000webhostapp.com/authorization.php?L="+userInputLogin.getText().toString()+"&P="+userInputPass.getText().toString()).get();
                        if((Res.equals(""))&&(Res!=null)){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Неверный логин или пароль", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            User.setName(Res);
                            User.setID(Integer.parseInt(new ThreadNews().execute("http://newsyou.000webhostapp.com/GetUserId.php?Name="+User.getName()).get()));
                            dialog.cancel();
                            LoadNews();
                        }
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Закрыть", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setNeutralButton("Регистрация", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

возникает ошибка `on a null object reference`  на строке `User.setName(Res)`.

Comment: Usef это что такое?

Comment: @Эникейщик, User это экземпляр класса UserClass

Comment: @MaNa, я бы посоветовал вам придерживаться соглашения об именовании, Экземпляры класса нужно именовать со строчной буквы, с заглавной буквы именуются сами классы. Тогда у других не возникало бы вопросов относительно `User`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было создать экземпляр, а не только объявить:

```
User=new UserClass("Visitor",-1);
```